# Standard type trait for the value of sizeof(T)

Tags: c++, c++11, std

The C++11 standard specifies a type trait `std::alignment_of<T>` which simply returns the value of `alignof(T)`.

Is there a similar trait for the `sizeof` operator?  Am I just missing it, or was it just missed in the standard, or is there some obscure technical reason why it wasn't specified?

Obviously it is trivial to create such a trait, but I can't imagine it wouldn't have been considered when introducing `std::alignment_of`.

For context, I have a custom type trait that I use to get the maximum value of a single trait when applied to a list of types.

```
template <template<class> class Trait, typename F, typename... T>
struct trait_max
  : std::integral_constant<decltype(Trait<F>::value),
      (Trait<F>::value > trait_max<Trait, T...>::value) ? Trait<F>::value : trait_max<Trait, T...>::value>
{ };
template <template<class> class Trait, typename F>
struct trait_max<Trait, F>
  : std::integral_constant<decltype(Trait<F>::value), Trait<F>::value>
{ };
```

This trait is really handy for when you need know the maximum of a set of types like so:

```
auto max_align = traits_max<std::alignment_of, int, float, std::string>::value;
auto max_size = traits_max<std::size_of, int, float, std::string>::value; // doesn't exist
```

Comment: Typo in your code, `Trait<T>` should be `Trait<F>` after the `?` operator.  I only noticed because this is awesome, and I'm so using it.

Comment: The only reason `std::alignment_of<T>` is in the standard is because it was part of TR1.

Comment: Fortunately, `template<typename T> struct size_of:std::integral_constant< std::size_t, sizeof(T) > {};` isn't hard to write either.

Comment: Thanks @SamCristall, fixed.  I have no idea why I didn't just copy the code in directly when I wrote the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::alignment_of` isn't new in C++11. It was added (along with the rest of `<type_traits>`) as part of TR1 in 2007. TR1's `<type_traits>` was copied wholesale from [Boost TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html), which provided `alignment_of` only because there was no standard way to get at that value in 2005.

Of course in 2005 there *was* a way to get the size of a type `T`; it has been spelled `sizeof(T)` since time immemorial. That's why `size_of<T>` wasn't in Boost TypeTraits, and *that's* why it wasn't copied into TR1 in 2007, and *that's* why it wasn't grandfathered into C++11.

As of 2011, there is **also** a standard way to get the alignment of a type `T`; it's spelled `alignof(T)`. The pre-2011 construct `std::alignment_of<T>::value` is needlessly verbose, and you almost certainly shouldn't be using it anymore unless you're concerned about portability to pre-2011 implementations.

I believe the most idiomatic way of writing your sample code is

```
size_t max_align = std::max({alignof(int), alignof(float), alignof(std::string)});
size_t max_size = std::max({sizeof(int), sizeof(float), sizeof(std::string)});
```

Once C++14 rolls around, `std::max` will become `constexpr`, so this will be computed at compile-time and be usable in template metaprogramming. But the suckiness of C++11's `std::max` is a totally separate issue, unrelated to your question. :)

**EDIT:** Here's a `constexpr_max` that works in today's C++11. Unfortunately C++11's `std::initializer_list` can't be used in a `constexpr` context; C++14 is fixing that too.

```
template<typename T> constexpr T constexpr_max(T t, T u) {
    return t > u ? t : u;
}

template<typename T, typename... TT> constexpr T constexpr_max(T t, TT... ts) {
    return constexpr_max(t, constexpr_max(ts...));
}
```

Comment: I'm using this trait in template metaprogramming, so the types in the sample code are normally upacked from a variadic template. Similar to your suggestion, `std::max({sizeof(T)...});` would be perfect, but without `constexpr` on `std::max` I'm forced to resort to a customized trait.

I guess I'm surprised this didn't come up during standardization.  If `alignment_of` was considered useless in an `alignof` world, why not depreciate it?  If it was still useful, why not add the analogous `size_of`? One of life's little mysteries...

Comment: Well, you're forced to resort either to "a customized trait" *or* to a custom constexpr `max` function, which you've actually already written, if you just remove the `trait_` cruft from your `trait_max`. :) I'll update my answer with sample code.